# Chirality in carbocations

Tags: chirality, carbocation

The following compound is a carbocation.

[image]

Clearly, the given compound does not have any element of symmetry. The compound is non planar due to the presence of ethyl group. Thus it must be chiral. But my book says the compound is achiral. How is this possible? Please explain.

Comment: It is planar.$\,$

Comment: @IvanNeretin, The carbocation carbon is $sp^2$ hybridised but the ethyl carbon is $sp^3$ hybridised, so the leftmost methyl group may be out of plane right?

Comment: The entire compound is not planar, but the bond geometry around the positive carbon is (trigonal) planar. All orientations of the ethyl group are equivalent.

Comment: @electronpusher, So the compound has plane of symmetry(plane along the screen) and thus is achiral right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: We must be checking the planarity only at the carbocation carbon and treat every other substituents as simply a spherical atom. I thought different conformers in the ethyl group leads to non-planarity, which can cause the system to exist in left and right handedness, thus chiral. But it seems too different. We must be considering only one carbon.

Comment: @GuruVishnu Essentially correct. You may want to look into the difference between Rotational Isomers and Optical Isomers.